# Иконки для ListViewItem по умолчанию и кастомные

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Проблема следующего характера. Есть `ListView` список, куда добавляются итемы, содержащие имя и путь к директории. При добавлении итема в список рядом с ним автоматически генерируется иконка (дефолтная) - это уже сделано.
 В последующем по пути, который указан в итеме, папка с файлами перекочует из одного места в другое.

Мне необходимо, чтобы после того, как папка была скопирована, дефолтная иконка заменилась на ту, которая в папке. Если в папке нету иконки, то оставалась дефолтная.

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: добавил, winforms

Answer (score 1):

Так у `ListView` есть свойства для иконок - `SmallImageList`,`StateImageList`, `LargeImageList` которые используются в зависимости от режима отображения `ListView` (свойство `ListView.View`). У `ImageList` при добавлении в него картинки можно указать `ImageKey`, а у `ListView.Items` использовать это свойство для связывания иконки и элемента `ListView`.

Соответственно, решаем задачу например, так:

```
...
//Назначаем ImageList для ListView, если еще не сделали этого в студии:
listView1.LargeImageList = imageList1;

//Загружаем дефолтную иконку в ImageList:
System.Drawing.Image defaultIcon = Image.FromFile(@"D:\Default.ico");
imageList1.Images.Add("DefaultIcon", defaultIcon);

//Путь к иконке:
string fi = @"D:\SomeFolder\Icon.ico";
//Имя иконки
string iconKey = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi);
//Загружаем иконку в ImageList
if (File.Exists(fi))
   {
    System.Drawing.Image folderIcon = Image.FromFile(fi);
    imageList1.Images.Add(iconKey, folderIcon);
   }
//Если иконка не найдена, используем иконку по-умолчанию:
else {iconKey = "DefaultIcon"}

//Подключаем иконку к элементу ListView:
listView1.Items[0].ImageKey = iconKey;
...
```

Если по каким-то причинам нужно удалить из `ImageList` иконку по ее ключу, то сделать это можно так:

```
imageList1.Images.RemoveByKey(iconKey);
```